Why did Robert mention space and time concept here?
In Oppenheimer (2023), Robert demonstrated his idea on the Manhattan Project on a board to General Leslie Groves:

Robert: All America's industrial might and scientific innovation,
connected by rail. Focused on one goal. One point in space and time.
And it comes together here.


When I google "space and time", it gives me Einstein's space-time.
Why did Robert mention space and time concept here?

It's how a physist would think. The "event" is given by where in space and time it occurs (at least in General Relativity). When you reverse time (decreasing entropy), it is also the reverse of an explosion: elements fly together to meet at (x,y,z,t). If you do not reverse time, you can get the same effect, at least locally, by applying computation (aka. "project organization, knowing where things are and directing them etc"), at the cost of increasing entropy as you go, as usual.

He's just making the point that it would be much more efficient that the the scientists that design and test the weapon be based in one place where they can work together.  Not split up into separate labs where they have to communicate by telephone and mail.
This lab is his 'one point in space and time'. Its just a grand/poetic way to phrase it, especially as the bomb itself is a point in space and time where it 'comes together'.
